# How to display 3 posts in a row in pyhton with html and css? It now displays every post under the last one

Tags: python, css, django, styles

I want to display like `col-md-4`  but it displays every post under the last one.

Ive tried to set the class of the container to `col-md-4` but it didn't work for me.
Can I define it directly into the container like I've tried or should I define it into CSS? 
I would be grateful if you can help me!

My code of my container is:

```
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

    {% block content %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="post">
                <div class="date">
                    {{ post.published_date }}
                </div>
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr | truncatewords:50 }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Weiterlesen</a>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

I have also an `base.py`

```
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Reminder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Code Reminder</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

my css looks like this, maybe i should define it into css?

`blog.css`

```
.page-header {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}


.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 36pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Ŕoboto', cursive;
}

.date {
    color: #828282;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}

.save {
    float: right;
}

.post-form textarea, .post-form input {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-menu, .top-menu:hover, .top-menu:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.post h2 a, .post h2 a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display your posts in columns use the `col-sm` class from bootsrap;

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-sm post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr | truncatewords:50 }}</p>
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Weiterlesen</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And in your base template, keep it simple;

```
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Reminder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Code Reminder</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The docs for this are here; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Working example; https://codepen.io/marksweb/pen/vMywPZ

Comment: Yeah, thats something I've tested before and nothing happens. It posts again one under the other and not in an grid style.

Comment: @UrosDobricic In that case, upgrade your version of bootstrap to 4.1. I've also included a link to a working example on codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution might be around using flexbox or grid. Flexbox is what bootstrap use behind in most of its components. I'd rather use this two amazing technologies than bootstrap. It gives you more control over your css.

I've prepared two simple examples using both of them to show you how to accomplish this:

flexbox:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7x98rme/4/

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

grid:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container__row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xu57ryqd/9/

Reference: https://gridbyexample.com/examples

If you need any additional explanation about my answer, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thats something I´ve also tried and it helped me more than the Bootstrap. But it won´t display it normally. There chaos when i set up this options.:D

Maybe you can try it out, i´ve made my blog public on GitHub. There you can see my code.

https://github.com/UrosDobricic/my-blog.git